# How do I change the color of a wireframe object

Tags: interface, customization, color, theme

How do I change the color of the cube (and the stuff behind it) to be different from the background color?

[image]

Comment: No, I've changed the background color, hoping that the wire mesh object would keep the same gray color, but it turns the same color as the background color. I want the wire mesh object (the faces of the wiremesh) to be a different color than the background, basically like Solid shading but without the shadows and with the wiremesh.

Comment: Your in wireframe mode, with x-ray turned off, this is the expected result. Put your viewport shading back in solid mode.

Comment: Are you saying it’s impossible to change the color or that it’s just the default to have it the same as the background?

Comment: I'm saying that in "wireframe" mode Blender is *only* displaying the "wireframe" (edges) of your models, it is not displaying the faces, so there is no colour to display. This is the default for wireframe mode. I usually turn on x-ray because I only use wireframe mode to see *through* my objects when needed. To display the faces you need to be in Solid mode.

Comment: It is displaying the faces too, as you said, you have to turn on x-ray to see through the object, and as you can see in the picture the faces are occluding everything behind it, so wireframe mode is actually rendering the faces, if it didn’t you would be able to see through them. So somewhere in blender theres a piece of code saying to render the faces using the background, Inwant to change that to a different color.

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/shading.html?highlight=wireframe

Comment: Ok, so short answer is that it’s impossible to set a solid color on the faces? :( I just have to live with the shading in solid mode? :(

Comment: Yep, but what's wrong with solid mode? You can set your background any colour you want and you get the shaded faces like you want.

Comment: Basically I want to still see the wires, so that I can more easily see how many polygons and such I have, it's much harder to see the lines on curved surfaces in solid mode.

Comment: Under Viewport Overlays, turn on Wireframe. It would have been good to add that detail to your original question :)

Comment: Oh, thanks. Ops, yeah, I should probably have said that in the original question... I'll rephrase the entire question later today and add your answer to it for anyone else to see.